# Backbone JS / Jasmine / Sinon : test if model has changed after event

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, sinon, jasmine-jquery

How can I test if a backbone view has triggered an event and then a model has been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your view is generating the `el` itself, you can cause it to trigger an event easily, through the view's `$el`.

```
describe("my test", function(){

  var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
      "click a": "aClicked"
    },

    aClicked: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.model.set({foo: "bar"});
    },

    render: function(){
      this.$el.html("<a href='#foo' id='fooLink'>foo</a>");
    }
  });

  var myModel;

  beforeEach(function(){
    myModel = new MyModel();
    var myView = new MyView({
      model: myModel
    });

    myView.render();

    // this will "click" the link
    myView.$("#fooLink").trigger("click");
  })

  it("should do that stuff", function(){
    expect(myModel.get("foo")).toBe("bar");
  });

});
```

Comment: Great! But how can I spy that the model has been set?

Comment: the test I wrote shows that... or i don't understand the question

Comment: It triggers the event but it doesn't check if the model has been called

Comment: @chchrist The fact the the value of `foo` is `bar` means the set was done. You *could* also `spyOn` your models `set` and `callThrough` expecting the spy has been called.

Comment: ah that's what I mean, I need to be sure that the foo is bar

Comment: @chchrist: the test very clearly verifies that the "foo" attribute has been set to "bar". perhaps you need to scroll down the code listing to see it?